# Aggregator Release Strategies with Annotations or Java DSL

Tags: spring-integration

I was trying to find a non-XML (Java Annotation/DSL) example of using timeout as a release strategy, but was unable to do so. (Such as TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy...)

My goal is to release after some delay since the last correlated entry was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `groupTimeout`. See `AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.setGroupTimeoutExpression()`.

If you are looking for the solution via annotation, you should consider to use `AggregatorFactoryBean` with the `@ServiceActivator` and `@Bean` annotations.

When we talk about Java DSL, there are `groupTimeout()/groupTimeoutExpression()` options on the `CorrelationHandlerSpec` when you configure an `.aggregate(a -> ...)` in the `IntegrationFlow`.

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#agg-and-group-to) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Artem. I was actually missing a call to .setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)